# OutOfMemory Error throws when try to deploy jars In Geode

Tags: deployment, geode

I try to deploy some jars which I'm going to use in Geode. Jars' total size is 74.19M. [deploy jars in Geode and OOM occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfvnv.png)

During this operation,OOM occurs. 
Then I do it again and this time I start Java VirtualVM to monitor the heap usage.[a screenshot of the heap usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5alt.png)

It's wired that the heap usage doesn't have any Fluctuations here.

Do you guys know why heap usage monitor doesn't show a sharp rise?
And how can I increase the heap size to avoid the OOM Error when I try to deploy jars in Geode?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your gfsh process is running out of memory not the locator or the server, so you don't see any change in heap on those processes.

You can change the amount of heap used by your gfsh process by setting JAVA_ARGS env variable. For example:

```
$ export JAVA_ARGS=-Xmx1024m
```

FYI, You can specify your heap size while starting the server and locator from gfsh:

```
gfsh>start locator --name=loc1 --initial-heap=512m --max-heap=512m
gfsh>start server --name=serv1 --initial-heap=1g --max-heap=1g
```